# using fixtures with ember-cli model blueprints

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Ok, this may be just a basic JS question.  I'm trying to create a model in ember-cli.  I've used the blueprints to make the initial file.  That gives me

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({

});
```

How would I add a fixture to this?

Answer (score 1):

This is some code I'm using with fixtures. The main thing is Recipe.reopenClass, Recipe.Fixtures isn't correct.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Recipe = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  steps: DS.attr(),
  description: DS.attr('string')
});

Recipe.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Spaghetti and meat",
      steps: ["Cook noodles", "add meat", "eat the food"],
      description: "ITS NOODLES AND MEAT"
    },

    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Gyro",
      steps: ["get lamb", "eat greek taco"],
      description: "ITS A TACO"
    }
  ]
});

export default Recipe;
```

Then in adapters/application.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();
```

Add this to your Brocfile

```
app.import({
  development: 'vendor/ember-data/ember-data.js',
  production:  'vendor/ember-data/ember-data.prod.js'
}, {
  'ember-data': [
    'default'
  ]
});
```

Comment: No, I know - I've seen these examples everywhere.  I guess my point is: when the code says `export default DS.Model.extend`, it creates a model object based on the file name.  So, unless I explicitly change the pattern/convention by setting the var, I don't know how to inject the fixture.  I've also been looking at the initializers, but they seem to be firing before the objects are instantiated (or I'm not pathing them correctly).

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking, do you mean are you allowed to use a defined model as in the example I gave? Or do you mean something else entirely?

Comment: I mean there's a syntactical disparity between what you wrote and the default template.  And, like I said, it may just be a simple JS answer.  I just haven't seen anything that explicitly states that `export default Blah.extend();` is semantically the same as `var B = Blah.extend(); B.reopenClass(); export default B;`

Comment: Assuming export default Blah.extend(); is named b, there is no real difference.